# What parts of AES encryption result are safe to pass on the network

Tags: aes

I'm using AES to encrypt the message.
both sender and receiver know the passphrase, but only sender knows IV and salt

I assume that receiver also needs to know IV and salt to decypher text;

is it safe to pass IV and salt along with the cyphertext over an unsecured network, or will this compromise the security?

I'm using https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js to send encrypted messages between multiple clients.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3436864/2194007) on SO, particularly [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3436997/2194007)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IVs and salts are public, so they are safe to pass with the ciphertext. They should be authenticated along with the ciphertext though.

Comment: If you use an authenticated encryption mode like GCM you don't have to worry about authenticating the IV.